# How to use extends in accesing the value super class

Tags: java, extends

I confused with extends, i went with theory n solved some examples,
But when i come to my main project still i am doing something wrong and i am not able to find it.

Can any one help me.

`ConnectionServiceImpl` is called by `RPC`

When the client call the COnnectionServiceImpl the connectionParameter is set .I checked it by display in the

```
Map<String, String>
```

but when second rpc call is done to the `ObjectStore`  by client
its give me error `NullPointerException` for the same `parameter` which was set in the `super` class

```
public class ConnectionServiceImpl extends RemoteServiceServlet{
// some code including initialization
private ConnectionParameter connectionParameter ;
private Map<String, String> parameter;
public String connection() {
        connectionParameter = new ConnectionParameter("abc","xyz",repositoryName);
        setConnectionParameter();
        setSession();
        return getConnected();
   }

protected  Map<String, String> getConnectionParameter() {
Iterator iterator = parameter.keySet().iterator();
         while(iterator.hasNext()){

                String key = iterator.next().toString();  
                String value = parameter.get(key);
                System.out.println("key  " + key  + " value "+value);

    }
            return parameter;
}

private void setConnectionParameter(){

    this.parameter=connectionParameter.getParameter();
}
}
```

This above class is working fine.

now,

```
public class ObjectStore extends ConnectionServiceImpl {
// some code
public ObjectStore() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    this.parameter = getConnectionParameter(); **<--- NullPointer Error**
            }
}
```

Can anybody explain this or tell the mistake

```
public class ConnectionParameter {

    private String repositoryID;
    private static String username;
    private static String password;
    private static String AtomPubUrl;
    private static String bindingType;
    private Map<String, String> parameter = new HashMap<String, String>();

    public ConnectionParameter(String username, String password,
            String repositoryId) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

        AtomPubUrl = "http://192.168.1.32:9083/CaseManager/resources/Service";
        bindingType = BindingType.ATOMPUB.value();
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
        this.repositoryID=repositoryId;

        setConnectionParameter();
    }
      Map<String, String> getParameter() {
        return parameter;
    }

    private void setConnectionParameter() {
        parameter.put(SessionParameter.USER,username);
        parameter.put(SessionParameter.PASSWORD, password);

        parameter.put(SessionParameter.ATOMPUB_URL,AtomPubUrl);
        parameter.put(SessionParameter.BINDING_TYPE, bindingType);

        parameter.put(SessionParameter.REPOSITORY_ID, repositoryID);
    }

}
```

Stacktrace

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.server.ConnectionServiceImpl.getConnectionParameter(ConnectionServiceImpl.java:107)
    at com.server.ObjectStore.<init>(ObjectStore.java:27)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:355)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:308)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Holder.newInstance(Holder.java:153)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.java:428)
```

Comment: add stack trace as well pls and possible more detail in code

Comment: how does the parent class constructor look like? the problem will go away if the default constructor of parent class were to initialize the the connection parameter.

Comment: @Scorpion :There no constructor.

Comment: @fmucar  I have added more details and Stack trace. Plz help.

Comment: @NewCodeLearner Please make sure the snippets you provide are accurate. Firstly, there's no way your `ObjectStore` class compiles when you've used `extends` twice. Secondly, what is `CmisConnectionServiceImpl` in the stack trace above?

Comment: @milkplusvellocet now its correct. That was because of copy n paste while adding more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to have a problem with initialization order and ownerhsip of member fields.

1. Have you initialized `ConnectionServiceImpl.parameter` in its constructor? You don't show any constructor there - do you have any? If not, then right after constructing the object, `parameter` is uninitialized. Which means that calling `getConnectionParameter` before `connection` gives you a null pointer. (Although it should not result in an NPE - is the code you show us really producing an NPE as you claim?).
2. From the above follows that your call to `getConnectionParameter` from the constructor of `ObjectStore` is an error, unless you have initialized `ConnectionServiceImpl.parameter` before (in the parent class constructor).
3. Apparently you either have a field called `parameter` in `ObjectStore` (which duplicates `ConnectionServiceImpl.parameter`, thus is highly discouraged), or `ConnectionServiceImpl.parameter` - whose declaration is not shown in your code - is not `private`, thus accessible from the subclass, and you are trying to initialize it from the subclass constructor (which is wrong in general - the base class should take care of initializing its fields properly). And if this is the case, you are actually attempting "circular initialization": to initialize the field in the subclass with its own value taken via the superclass getter, which is foolish.

Comment: I have added some details.According to me when the client call the ConnectionServiceImpl then the parameter is initialized, cause i checked it by displaying the value in `getConnectionParameter()` .  2. parameter is only intialzed after the client RPC call  3. `parameter ` in `ObjectStore ` is private. Still I have changed its name to parameter1.

Comment: @NewCodeLearner, you say `ConnectionServiceImpl` is called twice, and the NPE occurs the 2nd time. So it doesn't matter whether `parameter` is initialized the first time - you are creating a different object the 2nd time, and since `parameter` is not static, each object will have its own `parameter`. And since you say `ConnectionServiceImpl` has no constructor, my point 2 still applies. However, simply returning the null value of a field can not cause NPE - are you showing us the full code in `getConnectionParameter`?

Comment: @PéterTörök  I added what i have in the `getConnectionParameter`.But that code is just to display the `MAP`
May be my next question is stupid but i want know is where i am creating a new parameter.

Comment: I just want to access get value of parameter in `ObjectStore` class from `ConnectionServiceImpl`.

Comment: @NewCodeLearner, so there it is, in the code you just added: `Iterator iterator = parameter.keySet().iterator()` dereferences the null pointer, thus triggering the NPE. You are automatically creating a new `parameter` together with each new `ObjectStore` (or `ConnectionServiceImpl`) instance you are creating.

Comment: Buy making parameter Static ;i got the value in parameter.

Answer (score 0):

see that parameter value is set before you are calling `getConnectionParameter();`

call `setConnectionParameter();` where you feel required to avoid **NullPointerException**.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly I'd question why you have a member `connectionParameter` of type `ConnectionParameter` AND a member `parameter` of type `Map<String, String>` when you can just call `getParameter()`.

Secondly your methods are named in a confusing way. It's convention for setters to take a parameter of the type they're setting. Your `getConnectionParameter()` doesn't return `connectionParameter` at all.

Finally when you attempt to assign `parameter` in the subclass constructor it hasn't been initialised yet (unless you've done it in the superclass constructor).

Try to think about what you want to do here, the class `ConnectionServiceImpl` should be responsible for initialising its own members.

Comment: : i just want to use the value in `ConnectionServiceImpl.parameter ` in `objectStore` Class. The value of parameter is intialized buy the other class `ConnectionParameter`